# Passing values between methods c++

Tags: c++, class, parameter-passing

**Game.h**

```
#include "RandomNumberGenerator.h"


class Game
{
private:
    int myNumbers[6];
    int userRandomNumbers[6];
    int lotteryRandomNumbers[6];
    int prizeMoney;

public:

    void generateRandomNumbersLottery();
    void generateRandomNumbersUser();
    void userInputNumbers();
    void compareNumbers1();
    void compareNumbers2();
    void results();
};
```

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"

void Game::compareNumbers1()
{
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
        {
            if (myNumbers[i] == lotteryRandomNumbers[j])
            {
                k++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (k > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Congratulations you matched: " << k << " number(s)";
    }
    if (k == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Unfortunatly you matched: " << k << " numbers";
    }

}

void Game::compareNumbers2()
{
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
        {
            if (userRandomNumbers[i] == lotteryRandomNumbers[j])
            {
                k++;
            }
        }
    }


    if (k > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Congratulations you matched: " << k << " number(s)";
    }
    if (k == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Unfortunatly you matched: " << k << " numbers";
    }
}


void Game::results()
{
    if (k == 0)
    {
        prizeMoney = 0;
        std::cout << "Unfortunatly you need to match atleast 2 numbers to win a prize.";
    }
    if (k == 1)
    {
        prizeMoney = 0;
        std::cout << "Unfortunatly you need to match atleast 2 numbers to win a prize.";
    }
    if (k == 2)
    {
        prizeMoney = 3;
        std::cout << "Congratulations, you have won: 3 pounds."; 
    }
    if (k == 3)
    {
        prizeMoney = 30;
        std::cout << "Congratulations, you have won: 30 pounds."; 
    }
    if (k == 4)
    {
        prizeMoney = 3000;
        std::cout << "Congratulations, you have won: 3,000 pounds."; 
    }
    if (k == 5)
    {
        prizeMoney = 30000;
        std::cout << "Congratulations, you have won: 30,000 pounds."; 
    }
    if (k == 6)
    {
        prizeMoney = 3000000;
        std::cout << "Congratulations, you have won: 3,000,000 pounds."; 
    }
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"

    std::cout << "Do you wish to enter your own numbers or generate them randomly?: ('own',     'random') ";
    std::getline (std::cin, choice);
    if (choice == "random") 
    { 
        play.generateRandomNumbersUser(); 
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

        play.generateRandomNumbersLottery();
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

        play.compareNumbers2(); 
    }

    if (choice == "own") 
    { 
        play.userInputNumbers(); 
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
        play.generateRandomNumbersLottery(); 
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

        play.compareNumbers1(); 
    }

    play.results();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm aware this code has a lot of poor syntax etc in it at the moment but it currently just rough working code (i.e. no validation yet when choosing random or own numbers)

What I'm asking here is how do I get whatever value is in int k (from compareNumbers1() and compareNumbers2()) into results().

As far as my thinking goes it needs to be passed using a pointer somehow, or changing compareNumbers from void to int and return k. However after playing around with both these ways I still cannot get it to work.

Comment: Private member variables?

Comment: [Related previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20045624/560648)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use parameters. Pass the value as a parameter into results:

```
void results(int k);
```

Which leaves the question of how to get it out of `compareNumbers1()`. You could return it from that function:

```
int compareNumbers1();
```

If you need to put it into `compareNumbers2()`, let that method modify it, and then allow the caller to see the modifications you'd pass a reference to the variable:

```
void compareNumbers2(int& k);
```

And you'd clearly need to declare the variable somewhere. Since it is returned from `compareNumbers1()` you would declare it and assign it like this:

```
int k = compareNumbers1();
```

Put it all together at the call site and you have:

```
int k = compareNumbers1();
compareNumbers2(k);
results(k);
```

The obvious alternative to parameters is to make the variable be a private member variable of the class.

Comment: thanks - at first glance in the header file that seems to work (throws up no errors), however I'm unsure on how to call compareNumbers1(), compareNumbers2() and results() in main now, what do I put in the brackets (k, &k, int, int k and int &k all throw up errors)

Comment: baring in mind I changed compareNumbers1() to an int returning k, compareNumbers2(int& k) like that and results(int k) like that

Comment: My answer shows how to do it all. A private member variable might be easier. I just wanted to show you the basics of how to pass parameters which appears to be an as yet unlearnt area of programming for you. You need to choose better variable names too. This is not FORTRAN from the 50s. You are allowed to use variable names with more than one character!